# Expected number of SNPs in a sample of size `k`

Tags: evolution, population-genetics, theoretical-biology

Consider a Wright-Fisher population of constant size $N$. We sample $k$ haplotypes in this population. What is the expected number of SNPs?

I think the answer should be in [Watterson (1975)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040580975900209) but it looks like my institution does not pay for access to this journal.

Comment: Try using Sci-Hub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\theta = 4n\mu$, then $E(S) = \theta\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{i}$, assuming infinite sites model. This is indeed given by [Watterson (1975)](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1145509/).